# Por qué variable de entorno en Vite al importar (import.meta.env) sólo funciona en archivo ubicado en la raiz main.js?

Tags: vite, env

Tengo el env.local en la raiz del proyecto de la siguiente manera:

```
 VITE_CONEXION=MIGAN
VITE_PROVEEDOR=IS
VITE_CONSULTA=CONSULTALABEL1
VITE_CIA=1
```

solo me funciona la importación de las variables en el mismo nivel de ubicación del archivo env.local

al importar en cualquier otro archivo de otro nivel sale este error

[image: error que sale al ejecutarlo]

Comment: yo me perdi de algo, o porque haces node y no vite al ejecutar?

Comment: Hola, de antemano gracias por contestar. si es que es un archivo para consumir un web services y ahi tengo los datos sensibles, por eso quiero consumir las variables de entorno en dicho archivo y me toco asi porque el ws no tiene cors, entonces me toco ese puente. pero deberia funcionar al import.meta en ese archivo y no me funciona me dice undiefine, el proyecto lo componen el main.js y al mismo nivel el archivo xxx.js donde consumo el web services

Comment: vite reemplaza esas variables por sus valores al transpilar... en realidad una vez hecho eso, no existen esas variables.. por eso te dice que no las encuentra.. si no usas vite, no las va a encontrar... hay varios workaround por ahi...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que configurar el archivo vite.config.js utilizando la dependencia dotenv para traer las variables de entorno de tu archivo .env

Ejm:

En archivo .env

```
MI_VARIABLE_ENV=http://localhost:8080
```

En archivo vite.config.js, especificamente en la propiedad "define" defines las variables de entorno que se exportarán:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [],
  define: {
    'import.meta.env.MI_VARIABLE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.MI_VARIABLE_ENV)
  }
})
```

En cualquier archivo que vayas a usar la variable de entorno:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.MI_VARIABLE_ENV);
```